# How to force Visual Studio Code to accept double curly brackets as Tag Manager variables

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-tag-manager

I write a lot of Tag Manager tags, and I prefer to write them in the VScode before putting them into the TM. The TM uses double curly brackets as a notation of its variables (ex. `{{Page URL}}`, `{{Clicked Elements}}` etc.) I would love to set the VSC to recognize such notation as a variable and not consider it an error. I've googled extensively but either I cannot phrase the question correctly or no one faced this problem before. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set language as Django HTML, after installing some extension like this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django

I agree that it can be useful for complex code, while you loose the auto-completion feature for variable names in Google Tag Manager when you do so.